# Powershell SQL Select statements using csv variables

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In the code below, I'm trying to query a DB with multiple select statements using variables brought in from a `csv` and load a data-table using a reader.

The code runs without error but does not retrieve any data.

```
$csv = Import-Csv $filepath

$database = "DBNAME"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()

$sqlCommand = $connection.CreateCommand()
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

ForEach ($row in $csv){

   $query = "Select Emailaddress,Column2 from Users Where [Emailaddress] = '$row.Email'"

   $sqlCommand.CommandText = $query
   $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()  
   $DataTable.Load($DataReader)

}


$DataTable | export-csv "c:\Output\Seereader.csv" -NoTypeInformation
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried running the commands outside of a script?  That's step 1 in troubleshooting scripts. Verify your variables aren't null, all that business.

Comment: Yes - Without the loop I can successfully retrieve a single value $query = "SELECT EmailAddress, Geoname FROM Users where Emailaddress = 'oneoftheemails@email.com'"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

Comment: OK, then your problem is with your CSV file. Right away, I notice you're calling the variable incorrectly. If you want to access a property within string expansion, you need to use the propery syntax: `'$(row.Email)'"`

Comment: If I write this way $query = "Select Emailaddress,Column2 from Users Where [Emailaddress] = $row.Email" it gives a Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Must declare the scalar variable "@"." - I tried '$(row.Email)'" but it does not work.

Comment: You may have meant the same as @Mike Shepard answer '$($row.Email)'"? - You were right about the issue with the CSV - it did not separate the columns and I'm unsure why yet.

Comment: No, he just copied my comment into an answer.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/327/ Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$query = "Select Emailaddress,Column2 from Users Where [Emailaddress] = '$row.Email'"
```

Should probably be this:

```
$query = "Select Emailaddress,Column2 from Users Where [Emailaddress] = '$($row.Email)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the previous answer works, it is vulnerable to **SQL injection**.

## [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)

[image: xkcd: Explots of a Mom - xkcd.com]

If you're not sure what "SQL Injection" is; it's only a very worthy Google away...

*i.e. you really need to go and find out!*

## The correct way...

Parameterise your queries!

```
# Your query; with a @param
$Query = "SELECT Emailaddress, Column2 FROM [Users] WHERE [Emailaddress] = @emailAddress";

# Set up your basic command
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $Query

# Fill in the parameters!
$command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", $row.Email)

# Run boy, run!
$results = $command.ExecuteReader()

# Resultification (that's definitely not a made up word)
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$table.Load($results)
```

Safe and sound `:-)`

Comment: Definitely a good point that should always be used when adding parameters.